# Show $\frac{1}{4}\leq \mu(A\cap B \cap C)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\{X,\mathcal{A},\mu\}$ be a probability space. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be sets in $\mathcal{A}$, which satisfy
>
> $$\mu (A\cap B)\geq \frac{1}{2}, \quad \mu (A\cap C)\geq \frac{1}{2}, \quad \mu (B\cap C)\geq \frac{1}{2}.$$
>
> Show that $\frac{1}{4}\leq \mu(A\cap B \cap C)$.

I've managed to show in a previous assignment that $$\mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \min\{\mu (A\cap B), \mu (A\cap C), \mu (B\cap C)\},$$ but now I'm stuck with the above inequality. I've tried to draw it, but still no luck. Any hints?

Comment: Is "mu of A", the probability of A?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the set

$$D := (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C).$$

$\hspace{90pt}$[image]

Show that

$$\mu(D) = \mu(A \cap B)+\mu(B \cap C) + \mu(A \cap C) - 2 \mu(A \cap B \cap C).$$

Use $\mu(D) \leq 1$ to conclude that $\mu(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 1/4$.

Comment: +1. Which also provides that the equality case is when $\mu(A\cap B\cap C)=\mu((A\cap B)\setminus C)=\mu((B\cap C)\setminus A)=\mu((C\cap A)\setminus B)=\frac14$.

Comment: That is so nice!  Now I notice it is part of [Bonferroni inequalities](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bonferroni_inequalities).